# Is there an app which graphically logs/displays file-system I/O?

Tags: filesystem, software-recommendation, log

`System Monitor` gives me a graphical display of Network data flow.

Is there something similar for the data flow on the local file-system itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iostat -m`
shows the I/O per device that has been caused since system startup.

You can combine it with `watch 'iostat -m'`

Comment: I like this program, thanks! Answer a question learn something new along with it. :)

Comment: Thanks... Your `iostat` and NightwishFan's `iotop` work well together in a split Terminal window (the broad picture, and the detail).

Answer (score 3):

There is a System Monitor gnome-panel applet that shows a tiny graph of IO. Also you can use the program iotop, which is like top/htop in the console though for I/O.

Comment: I like this program, thanks! **Ask** a question learn something new along with it. :)  .... This one has finer resulion; I like that...  It's hard to pick the "best" answer, because my question asked about a "general" situation.. I'll ponder it over a cup of coffee :)

Comment: `iotop` works well enough (for me), but my kernal isn't compiled suitably to allow it to output some of its features...  `CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT not enabled in kernel, cannot determine SWAPIN and IO %` ... I don't know what they are, so it doesn't much matter.. :)

Comment: Glad it works for you. :)